# Cloud Functions for Firebase: Make a Get Request and return body

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am implementing Cloud Functions for Firebase, where when triggered makes a GET request and I want it to return the body, but it doesn't return anything.

```
"use strict";
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var request = require('request');
var rp = require('request-promise');
exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {


var url = 'https://api.pipl.com/search/?url=https://www.linkedin.com/in/akberaliengineer/&key=BUSINESS-PREMIUM-DEMO-vg6sygfm5wgnvpznkl8btq7c'

return request(url, function (error, response, body) {

  res.send(body);
});
});
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does it say in the Firebase console log for Functions?  What payment tier is your project in?

Comment: Yes, your right , I was on the Spark plan, switched to the Blaze plan. Thanks

Comment: Could you answer this question with your resolution, and accept it, so that others might be helped in the future?

Comment: My account is not allowed to answer, if someone answers, I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Cloud Functions, outbound HTTP requests to non-Google services require the project to be on the [Blaze payment plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) to activate billing.